# Python: NagAconda installation throw error

Tags: python, pip

I am new on Python can any please help me out regarding this error I have installed

`python 3.3`
`pip 1.4`

but unable to install `NagAconda` through pip

My machine is windows 7

The error is gievn below:-

```
   C:\Python33>"c:\python33\scripts\pip.exe" install NagAconda
   Downloading/unpacking NagAconda
   Downloading NagAconda-0.2.1.tar.gz (235kB): 235kB downloaded
   Running setup.py egg_info for package NagAconda
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
   File "c:\users\rajars~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_rajarshid\NagAconda\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
   import NagAconda
   File ".\NagAconda\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
   from Plugin import *
   ImportError: No module named 'Plugin'
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<string>", line 16, in <module> 

   File "c:\users\rajars~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_rajarshid\NagAconda\setup.py", line 4, in <module>

   import NagAconda

   File ".\NagAconda\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

   from Plugin import *

   ImportError: No module named 'Plugin'

   ----------------------------------------
   Cleaning up...
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\rajars~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_rajarshid\NagAconda
   Storing complete log in C:\Users\rajarshid\pip\pip.log

   C:\Python33>pause
   Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please help me I search in google but not get any kind of help

Comment: I also crated an issue on github but no response till https://github.com/trifthen/NagAconda/issues/4

Comment: it looks like that the package NagAconda is broken. if the module plugin is their own code, this module is missing from the package or is not well called ; for example `from NagAconda import Plugin` instead. in any case I strongly think that the package is broken

Comment: @FoxMaSk Pleae post your comment so that I can accept it or I will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like that the package NagAconda is broken.

if the module plugin is their own code, this module is missing from the package or is not well called.

For example

```
from NagAconda import Plugin
```

instead.

in any case I strongly think that the package is broken